# Discussion about moderation decisions belong in meta

Tags: discussion, moderation

Extended discussion about moderation decisions belong in meta, not in question comments or in answers themselves.

Recently some of my moderation decisions have been questioned by a new participant in this Stack. I am not a fan of censorship and want to make everyone feel welcome on Monero SE. Any questions, comments or criticism about moderation practices can be raised here.

I ask that offensive language such as use of the words `retarded`, `gestapo` or `shitcoin` not be used when discussing moderators, any member of this community or Monero itself, particularly in a SE question, comment, or answer. I stand by my decision to delete comments with any such language.

Secondly I ask that SE answers to the extent possible, be answered here on Stack Exchange. Answers that are *largely comprised* of links to external personal blog posts (or similar) are not ideal for a number of reasons. People come here for answers, not to find a link (which can become dead links over time) to read answers somewhere else.

Finally, SE is not the best place for extended debates within the question comments section (particularly if some of the comments you are responding to are very old). Instead, provide another answer to the question, create a new question and/or answer or use [Monero SE chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42720/monero) where appropriate.

The contributions of all users are welcome on Monero SE. I don't claim to be perfect. Please feel free to make discussion moderation decisions or make suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of problems I'm seeing with questions:

1. Users asking the same question in GitHub issues, reddit and here. As someone who is on all these channels this is frustrating. For me, GitHub should be for reporting bugs, reddit for posting links and having discussion, here for asking questions.
2. Often there are questions that a very quick search answers. When the question is answered elsewhere (see above point), posting a link to that offsite answer feels the right thing to do. The person who answered it gets the credit, even though it's not on Monero SE.

Personally, I am trying hard to respond to as many questions as possible here for the main reason I'm fed up with the misuse of the Monero GitHub issues being used as a support channel instead of it's intended purpose as a bug tracker.